# What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I want to know: What is android:weightSum and layout weight, and how do they work?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Per documentation, `android:weightSum` defines the maximum weight sum, and is calculated as the sum of the `layout_weight` of all the children if not specified explicitly.

Let's consider an example with a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and 3 `ImageViews` inside it. Now we want these `ImageViews` always to take equal space. To acheive this, you can set the `layout_weight` of each `ImageView` to 1 and the `weightSum` will be calculated to be equal to 3 as shown in the comment.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- android:weightSum="3" -->
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"/>
  .....
```

`weightSum` is useful for having the layout rendered correctly for any device, which will not happen if you set width and height directly.

Comment: This is not an explanation of the purpose of `weightSum`.  The behavior in your example would be identical with `weightSum` omitted, and in fact weightSum should not be specified in that scenario.  The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) says, `weightSum Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children.`

Comment: @JeffAxelrod: It "should not" be specified? Why? I see no reason for that. So I would just say it does not need to be specified.

Comment: @MarcoW.: It should not be specified because of maintainability.  As Jeff said, setting the weightSum to be equal to the sum of the weights inside the layout accomplishes nothing, but if someone changes it in the future it could cause headaches as now there is an unnecessary modifier to the layout that would have to be found and changed.  This answer is incorrect and should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: Don't see a good explanation of weightSum parameter, so from docs: "This can be used for instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0." See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum

Comment: The idea is that you can set weightSum to a number higher than the sum of the children. This causes the children to receive some but not all of the available extra space. In the example above, your single child would inherit half of the available space instead of all of it.

Comment: Response 2 years late, but could it actually be more optimized to declare a weightSum even in the weight=1, =1, =1 scenario, given that the calculation of the totaling the child weights is done in advance? That width ratio result could be calculated in real time as the child views are being read through, without having to do any full passes through the child list beforehand.

Of course having multiple connected values to coordinate during every code change impacts maintainability, but this seems like an O(1) solution for something previously O(n).

Answer (score 183):

Adding on to superM's and Jeff's answer,

If there are 2 views in the LinearLayout, the first with a layout_weight of 1, the second with a layout_weight of 2 and no weightSum is specified, by default, the weightSum is calculated to be 3 (sum of the weights of the children) and the first view takes 1/3 of the space while the second takes 2/3.

However, if we were to specify the weightSum as 5, the first would take 1/5th of the space while the second would take 2/5th. So a total of 3/5th of the space would be occupied by the layout keeping the rest empty.

Comment: I was looking for the same, that what if weightsum is not defined and weights are provided to the child views.
Your answer that it calculates own its own cleared everything

Comment: Is it true that is recommended to use RelativeLayout than Layouts with weightSum?

Answer (score 32):

Weight sum works exactly as you want (like other answers you don't have to sum all the weights on parent layout). On child view specify the weight you want it to take. **Don't forget to specify**

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Following is an example

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="30%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="20%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="50%"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
                </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

This will look like

[image]

Answer (score 25):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum) says it best and includes an example, (highlighting mine).

> android:weightSum
>
> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a **single** child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

So to correct superM's example, suppose you have a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation that contains two `ImageViews` and a `TextView` with.  You define the `TextView` to have a fixed size, and you'd like the two `ImageViews` to take up the remaining space equally.

To accomplish this, you would apply `layout_weight` 1 to each `ImageView`, none on the `TextView`, and a `weightSum` of 2.0 on the `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 21):

After some experimenting, I think the algorithm for LinearLayout is this:

Assume that `weightSum` is set to a value. The case of absence is discussed later.

First, divide the `weightSum` by the number of elements whith `match_parent` or `fill_parent` in the dimension of the LinearLayout (e.g. `layout_width` for `orientation="horizontal"`). We will call this value the weight multiplier [image: w_m] for each element. The default value for `weightSum` is 1.0, so the default weight multiplier is `1/n`, where `n` is the number of `fill_parent` elements; `wrap_content` elements do not contribute to `n`.

[image: w_m = weightSum / #fill_parent]

E.g. when `weightSum` is 60, and there are 3 `fill_parent` elements, the weight multiplier is 20. The weight multiplier is the default value for e.g. `layout_width` if the attribute is absent.

Second, the maximum possible expansion of every element is computed. First, the `wrap_content` elements are computed according to their contents. Their expansion is deducted from the expansion of the parent container. We will call the remainer `expansion_remainer`. This remainder is distributed among `fill_parent` elements according to their `layout_weight`.

Third, the expansion of every `fill_parent` element is computed as:

[image: w_m - ( layout_weight / w_m ) * maximum_possible_expansion]

Example:

If `weightSum` is 60, and there are 3 `fill_parent` elements with the weigths 10, 20 and 30, their expansion on the screen is 2/3, 1/3 and 0/3 of the parent container.

```
weight | expansion
     0 | 3/3
    10 | 2/3
    20 | 1/3
    30 | 0/3
    40 | 0/3
```

The minimum expansion is capped at 0. The maximum expansion is capped at parent size, i.e. weights are capped at 0.

If an element is set to `wrap_content`, its expansion is calculated first, and the remaining expansion is subject to distribution among the `fill_parent` elements. If `weightSum` is set, this leads to `layout_weight` having no effect on `wrap_content` elements.
However, `wrap_content` elements can still be pushed out of the visible area by elements whose weight is lower than [image: weight multiplier] (e.g. between 0-1 for `weightSum`= 1 or between 0-20 for the above example).

If no `weightSum` is specified, it is computed as the sum of all `layout_weight` values, *including* elements with `wrap_content` set! So having `layout_weight` set on `wrap_content` elements, *can* influence their expansion. E.g. a negative weight will shrink the other `fill_parent` elements.
Before the `fill_parent` elements are laid out, will the above formula be applied to `wrap_content` elements, with maximum possible expansion being their expansion according to the wrapped content. The `wrap_content` elements will be shrunk, and afterwards the maximum possible expansion for the remaining `fill_parent` elements is computed and distributed.

This can lead to unintuitive results.

Answer (score 10):

If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0. Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2"

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2.0" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#0000FF" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#00FF00" >
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 'May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".' (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)

Answer (score 7):

One thing which seems like no one else mentioned: let's say you have a **vertical** `LinearLayout`, so in order for the weights in layout/element/view inside it to work 100% properly - all of them must have **`layout_height`** property (which must exist in your xml file) set to `0dp`. Seems like any other value would mess things up in some cases.

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" is usually used instead of 0dp

Comment: why is that so? I mean you are right it is messing up, but  setting height to 0 dp fied my problem. i would to know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

**Layout Weight works like a ratio.** For example, if there is a vertical layout and there are two items(such as buttons or textviews), one having layout weight 2 and the other having layout weight 3 respectively. Then the 1st item will occupy 2 out of 5 portion of the screen/layout and the other one 3 out of 5 portion. Here 5 is the weight sum. i.e. **Weight sum divides the whole layout into defined portions.**
**And Layout Weight defines how much portion does the particular item occupies out of the total Weight Sum pre-defined.** Weight sum can be manually declared as well. Buttons, textviews, edittexts etc all are organized using weightsum and layout weight when using linear layouts for UI design.

Answer (score 1):

From developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)

This can be used for instance to give a single child `50%` of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of `0.5` and setting the weightSum to `1.0`.

Addition to @Shubhayu answer

rest `3/5` can be used for other child layouts which really doesn't need any specific portion of containing layout.

this is potential use of `android:weightSum` property.

Answer (score -1):

No one has explicitly mentioned that `weightSum` is a particular XML attribute for `LinearLayout`.

I believe this would be helpful to anyone who was confused at first as I was, looking for `weightSum` in the `ConstraintLayout` documentation.