# layout_weight for RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android

There is the following code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationYesterdayValueDisplay"
                android:layout_width="15dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationYesterdayValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:max="10"
                android:progress="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Now I need to change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. If I do it then RelativeLayout fill the whole screen, and it's bad. I understand that RelativeLayout doesn't use layout_weight for its work. Please, tell me, how can I fix it? I've tried to make LinearLayout wrapper for RelativeLayout, but it doesn't help.

UPDATE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
UPDATE 2: FUll code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="1.0"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationYesterdayValueDisplay"
                        android:layout_width="15dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/activityEvaluationYesterdayValue"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationYesterdayValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:max="10"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Yesterday"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationTodayValueDisplay"
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationTodayValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:max="10"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Today"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationTomorrowValueDisplay"
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationTomorrowValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:max="10"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Tomorrow"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationEnergyValueDisplay"
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationEnergyValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:max="10"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView11"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Energy"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationWeatherValueDisplay"
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationWeatherValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:max="10"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView09"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Weather"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationHoursSleptValueDisplay"
                        android:layout_width="20dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.ulnda.mypsych.views.VerticalSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/activityEvaluationHoursSleptValue"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:max="10"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Hours Slept"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why RelativeLayout fill whole screen, not 0.6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` is the only one child who has `layout_weight` attribute so you should also specify `weightSum`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! Please, tell me, where can I read about weightSum? I don't know anything about it.

Comment: If your first code works for `LinearLayout` it should also work for `RelativeLayout` as well. You can read about `weightSum` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Please, look at my second update. This code doesn't work properly. I've just change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and add some attributes to childs of RelativeLayout. Please, look at this.

Answer (score 6):

`android:layout_weight` makes sense only for `LinearLayout`. Lint should aware you about with a warning

Comment: But how can I do my task? I need to use RelativeLayout in order to align my VerticalSeekBar by center and TextView by left of VerticalSeekBar

Comment: RelativeLayout has lot of methods to place things. For instance layout_toLeftOf  Check the documentation

Comment: I know it, but I can't just use RelativeLayout because it fill all screen space. Please, tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: it fills the screen space because for every element you declare inside it you should provided its position

Comment: there is nothing inside the RelativeLayout. Then with match_parent you are asking to fill all the available space. Maybe you want to give to "wrap_content" a try?

Comment: It hasn't help. Please, edit my code, may be I don't understand you quietly.