# Equal TextView in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I would like to create in my application statistics from a'la tiles metro. Unfortunately TextView hasn't equal width, as it solved?

[This is my layout](http://pastebin.com/i24g6Uzs)

Comment: As far as I have understood, the problem may be due to the fact that you have put android:layout_width="match_parent" ,try giving it a value to match your needs

Comment: hi Artur, welcome to the community, can you please describe more about your problem?

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to mimic other UI elements like said in android design guidelines here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: This is my layout :  http://postimg.org/image/lz45maoo1/ unfortunately tiles extend depending on the length of the text with TextView

Answer (score 0):

Use [android:weightSum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work) and android:layout_weight

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#B0B0B0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#B0B0B0" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```