# LinearLayout dividers are not showing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am working on an android project and I have a LinearLayout which contains 2 horizontal buttons using borderless button style.

I am trying to show dividers in between each button but they are not showing up but I can't see any reason why not. Below is the XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/call_log_select_host_button_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:dividerPadding="22dp">
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnBlock"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Block"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: A silly question but what color is your background?

Comment: It the Theme.Holo.Dialog which is a dark background

Comment: dont forget the infuriating **SHOWDIVIDERS** item !!!!!!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Create a file `mydivider.xml` inside `res/drawable` and put the following shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="1dip" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

add the shape as divider for your layout

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/call_log_select_host_button_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/mydivider"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:dividerPadding="22dp">
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnBlock"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Block"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

or as workaround:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/call_log_select_host_button_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/mydivider"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:dividerPadding="22dp">
        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

         <View    android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/call_log_select_btnBlock"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Block"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this doesnt works on android 2.2 .

Comment: @BasavarajHampali but you can use the LinearLayoutICS in the support library, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547897/how-to-add-dividers-to-linearlayoutics/

Comment: it does not work for my app targeting Android 4.4.2 with min API 11

Comment: @legr3c: Don't make rubbish edits.

Comment: Instead of writing your own mydivider.xml file, you can also reference one from the current theme, i.e. android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" or android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical" - works on API 11 and above.

Comment: @NicolaiBuch-Andersen's answer shall be the best.  it works on Android 4.4.3 (i didn't test others)

Answer (score 10):

Try replacing `android:divider="#ffffff"` with `android:divider="@android:color/white"`. My suspicion is that `divider` has to be a Drawable, and hard-coding the color may not treat it like a Drawable, but referencing it might.

Comment: You're right. Switched from color to drawable and voila! Working. Accepted answer has great example

Answer (score 0):

You should add `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in your LinearLayout. That way it will show ;)

Comment: Doing that breaks the layout as the content above the button group doesn't show only the buttons at the top of the activity and the dividers still didn't show

Comment: and adding a `android:weightSum=""` in your LinearLayout? Will that solve your problem?

Comment: I've tried setting weightSum to 2 as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work but it still shows the button group at the top taking the top with the content that's supposed to be above the buttons not showing and the dividers aren't showing

Comment: `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` is only implemented in Android 4.0 if I'm correct. Do you have it set to android 4.0+?
EDIT: it's implemented in API level 11

Comment: I'm targetting Jelly Bean, the button borderless attribute is working as expected its just the dividers which aren't