# How to give 20 screen width to an ImageView

Tags: android

How do I create an UI header like this image?

[image]

I'm using the code below but how do I adjust 30% of the screen to the image and 70% to a TextView. I also use two TextViews on that 70% of width. This is my code, it does not look as in the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LinearLayout   
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:orientation="vertical" >



  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#=#EFECE5"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 


    />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="San Diego Uified"
       />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="School District"
      />

    </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

add `android:layout_weight="3"` property to image and `android:layout_weight="7"` to text

Comment: and also  setting linearlayout's weight_sum to 10 may help

Answer (score 0):

checkout `weight` for `textviews` and `imageviews` and `weightSum` for `LinearLayout`

[What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "android:layout_weight"

Assigning a value  'android:layout_weight' will split up the available space in the parent View, according to the value of each View‘s layout_weight and its ratio to the overall layout_weight specified in the current layout for this and other View elements.

In your case

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#=#EFECE5"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_weight="30"

    />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="San Diego Uified"
        android:layout_weight="35"
       />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="School District"
        android:layout_weight="35"
      />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000" android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Header Layout -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="0.30" >
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="San Diego Uified"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
       />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="School District"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
      />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Body layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="School aasdadadad adasd"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```