# split LinearLayout via percent

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to make a LinearLayout like this by percent
[image]

each rectangle is a LinearLayout

is that possible to make and how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear Layout and weight in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this sample xml...this will helpfull to understand the `weightSum` and `layout_weight` in the `LinearLayout`

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="Button20" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="Button20" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="Button20" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:text="Button40" />
```

Comment: use android:layout_width="0dp" for each Button. If the orientation  is horizontal.

Comment: Oops Sorry!! Forgotten!! Thanks:)

Comment: @Namecan'tbedisplayed Please flag the question as a duplicate next time. I understand your good will to answer and help, but please try to keep things organized whenever you see a satisfactory answer elsewhere, as your own answer says when linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this One:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="100" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="20%" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="20%" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="20%" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:text="40%" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each `cell`'s width equal to `match_parent` and then play with the `layout_weight` value for each child. As layout_weight specifies size ratio between multiple elements, i.e.