# Android ActionBar custom layout styling

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar

I'm just starting android development coming from IOS and again stubbled onto a problem.
And after 1 day of trying i decided that i will ask the people of stack overflow.

So my problem:

I have an app and in the action bar (default no sherlock) i want 1 logo and 2 lines of text.
And trough the internet i fount the setCustomView for the action bar.
And the custom xml is loaded but i can't get the layout right.

So first i setup the action bar:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null); // layout which contains your button.

    actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp1);
}
```

Than the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/Blue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_menu"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_help"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the result is something what i'm not looking for:

[image: Problem in an image]

So what am i forgetting/doing wrong/or should i do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try change the root layout into relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:text="left text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/text_left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_sunrise"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Right txt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:id="@+id/text_right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I love you, its done i waisted 1 day. And now i can go on. Thanks

Comment: Thanks this was useful. If you need a different layout, always use a RelativeLayout as root!

Answer (score 2):

## you're not getting your result because:

[image]

u need to:

1. if you use AppCompat theme

[image]

2. add to your activity layout

[image]

3. in code eg. in onCreate() set a toolbar to replace the action bar.

[image]

Comment: Absolute madlad, screenshoted the codes. Thanks for helping btw

Answer (score 0):

You could also use LinearLayout as a root and add android:weightSum and specify a layout_weight on the three child views.

[What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)