# How to Control Menu Position in Toolbar Android

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-toolbar

I want to change the gravity of my inflated menu item in android xml code but i could not find any attribute to solve the problem. **i want an item in the `left` side and another item in `right` side of corner in `Toolbar`**.

Do you have any idea guys?

**Here's my present state:**

[image: screenshot of toolbar]

**Here's my menu xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dismis"
        android:icon="@drawable/close"
        android:title="Done"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/saveNote"
        android:icon="@drawable/save"
        android:title="Done"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>


</menu>
```

Comment: Try using Toolbar in your layout with necessary NoActionBar theme  .Then it will be much easier for you to customize the menu items .

Comment: You mean its not possible with default toolbar??? @RishabhMaurya

Comment: No , I didn't mean that ! @Thats Enam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Toolbar` navigation `item`(`LEFT`) for `dismiss` item and option `menu`(`RIGHT`) for `saveNote` item.

**Dismiss:**

> You can use `Toolbar` navigation `item` as `dismiss` action. Set
>   `close` icon as `Toolbar` navigation icon by using
>   `Toolbar.setNavigationIcon()`. To handle the `click` event, add
>   `NavigationOnClickListener` to `Toolbar`.

**SaveNote:**

> Inflate `menu` XML to `Toolbar` using `Toolbar.inflateMenu()`. To
>   handle `saveNote` item `click` event, add `OnMenuItemClickListener` to
>   `Toolbar`.

**Follow below steps:**

**1.** Remove `dismiss` item from `menu` XML.

```
// menu_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/saveNote"
        android:icon="@drawable/save"
        android:title="Done"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**2.** In your activity, do below changes for `dismiss` and `saveNote` actions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    // ToolBar
    Toolbar mToolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...........
        .....................

        // ToolBar
        mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        // Required to use Toolbar as ActionBar
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("StackOverflow");

        // Dismiss Action
        mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.close);
        mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Do something
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // SaveNote Action
        mToolBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        mToolBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.saveNote)
                {
                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        .............
        ....................... 
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: it worked.thanks man.but i cant find the id of that item (dismiss button) to get things easier. @FAT

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, no need to add dismiss item in `menu.xml`. You can programmatically use Toolbar navigation item for dissmiss action. See step 2. I have commented in activity codes. mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.close);
        mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Do something
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: ops you didnt understand what i mean.i want to get the id of that icon like android.R.id.home! now got it???

Comment: Its your own icon. You have to add a close/dismiss icon into your drawable folder. Then use it as usual R.drawable.your_icon.

Comment: "i want to get the id of that icon like android.R.id.home!" >>> If you want to handle it from `onOptionItemselected` method then still you can use `android.R.id.home` to handle the dismiss action. But for this cases you don't need `mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener()`. Hope you understand.

Comment: did you applied this >> getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); I have checked it few minutes ago in my pc and its working fine. Here is the code: @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

Answer (score 0):

well, you have to make a custom layout and then attach it to your appbar!
you can check here

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972324/android-actionbar-custom-layout-styling)
[link2](http://www.journaldev.com/9952/android-custom-action-bar-example-tutorial)

to make a custom layout for appbar in your activity

Comment: pleasure that you replied quickly.