# How to make application responsive for all android devices?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am creating one application and I want my application to open without any issue with view,I tried to use weightsum attribute for that but I do not know why it shows different views all time in different devices,check this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/backgroundgd"
 android:weightSum="100.0"
 >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:background="@drawable/another"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:background="@drawable/secondpart"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

in bluestack it looks like this
[image]

Comment: please put screenshots of view, how they are showing different.

Comment: Can you share desired output  ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ i want my view looks same in all devices

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: use *match_parent* instead of *wrap_content*

Comment: @SweetWisherツ so will it look good and suppoerted in all devices?

Comment: wrap_content will just use space which are used by inner component. while match_parent will use all space of device's screen.

Comment: Ya, but to be more specific with all controls you wanna add in xml , follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: @SweetWisherツ tell me exact use of weightsum and wight

Comment: even you can check your layout graphically in xml part, switching to `graphical Layout` in eclipse as well as Android studio.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ i dint get that tutorials,what should i do

Comment: Try to understand it, it will help in future when you will work with bigger apps.

Comment: @Johnson check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Johnson this example may help you.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `"match_parent"` of `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/backgroundgd"
 android:weightSum="100.0">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_cntent"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:background="@drawable/another"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:background="@drawable/secondpart"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give match_parent width and height in container LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundgd"
>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:background="@drawable/another"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:background="@drawable/secondpart"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, you are using weight incorrectly.

> Weight sum and weight is used to divide screen portion equally between some elements. So if you give weightsum = "3" in container layout, and its 3 children layout mention weight="1", then all three children uses up 33.33% part of container layout. And at that time width and height are kept as 0 dp according to container layout's orientation.

Comment: what is usee of weight sum and weight

Comment: Weight sum and weight is used to divide screen portion equally between some elements. So if you give weightsum = "3" in container layout, and its 3 children layout mention weight="1", then all three children uses up 33.33% part of container layout. And at that time width and height are kept as 0 dp according to container layout's orientation.