# defining width and height to layouts android

Tags: android, android-layout

my requirement is to make 10 layouts in a single layout . Each layout should be 50 % horizontally and 20% Vertically.

Current my code can make horizentally 50% but how to make same layouts to 20% vertical.

Can it be possible.

Code is

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutouter" android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
    <Button android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes it is possible by adding equal weight to each layout

Comment: Can you please give some code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u should add another child layout in your linear layout to avoid nested weight.
and check this [What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

try this..hope works fo u..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutouter"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" >
            </Button>

            <!-- added 8 mote view with weight 1 -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with nested layouts, like a grid.

```
<!-- Row 0 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Row 0: Column 0-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button ... />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Row 0: Column 1-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button ... />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
...

...
<!-- Row 4 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Row 4: Column 0-->
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks a bit odd, maybe you could consider using a ListView or any other strategy that fits better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use weightSum property like below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 3 more rows here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Outer weightSum is used for 5 rows. And inner weightSum is used for 2 columns