# How to make two buttons to be equal size and occupying all their parent's width?

Tags: android

There are two buttons :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layoutWidth="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/btn1"
       android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Launch camera"
       android:onClick="launchCamera" />

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/btn2"
       android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="List of photos"
       android:onClick="listPhotos" />

</linearLayout>
```

How to make these two buttons having equal size and spanning all their parent's width ?

Comment: You can't do this. The `|` operator is a binary OR which can only be used for ORing numeric values. Trying to overlay more than one background is completely different. You'd need to use a `FrameLayout` for that and apply each image separately in code.

Comment: @Squonk Can you post an answer with an example please ?

Comment: http://myandroidtipsandtricks.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/drawables-part-ii.html

Comment: Wow 100 reputation just for this?

Comment: This is a horizontal layout, meaning the buttons are side by side, and you want both of them to fill the parent?

Comment: @ pheromix Have you tried to set width of the buttons to fill parent (or better match parent)?

Comment: The edit history is just weird.

Comment: @pheromix Can you choose an answer?

Comment: I'll choose an answer after giving the bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use weights:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
   <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Launch camera"
       android:onClick="launchCamera" />
   <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="List of photos"
       android:onClick="listPhotos" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: bounty can be awarded after 9h , @moictab will be given it :)

Answer (score 4):

By using "weightSum" attribute at LinearLayout and "layout_weight" and "width" = zero at its children (Buttons) and this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776742/753616) for explaining What is android:weightSum and how it works in Android

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Launch camera"
        android:onClick="launchCamera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List of photos"
        android:onClick="listPhotos" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Answer:

Very important, both `buttons` are aligned side by side(`android:orientation="horizontal"`) and notice that there is a `android:layout_weight="1"`.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Launch camera"
        android:onClick="launchCamera" />
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List of photos"
        android:onClick="listPhotos" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please see other examples here: [Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

### Example of the weights, using just layouts and colors:

[image]

Comment: The default weigth sum is 1.0, so `layout_weight` of 0.5 should be enought for both `Button`s ;)

Comment: @shkschneider Then why didn't you do so in your answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I actually did, sir. Anyway, all our answers work ^^

Comment: @shkschneider Do you mean (at) jegesh?

Comment: Yes, sorry. @jegesh: I precisely did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use android:weightSum on the LinearLayout and android:layout_weight on your Buttons.

```
<LinearLayout android:layoutWidth="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="center">
   <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
       android:layoutWidth="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Launch camera"
       android:onClick="launchCamera" />
   <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
       android:layoutWidth="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="List of photos"
       android:onClick="listPhotos" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [LinearLayout Weight](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="Launch camera"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:onClick="launchCamera" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:text="List of photos"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"  />    
</LinearLayout>
```

The default weight sum is 1.0, so 0.5 is enough in this example of 2 children Views.