# How to set textView as right as possible and set textView show only a part of text?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have the xml code shown below. Everything is working as it should except the final textView( id locationTextView) which won't stay right. I want it to stay as right as possible, but I can't do that(it still appears straight after the linear Layout).Should I set a left margin?. And for the textView1 how can I make it to show only a certain part of the whole text, because I have texts of different lengths and they ruin the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/product_list_item_bg"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_margin="3dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#33CC33" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/locationTextView"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:layout_weight="1"` or some other value for your `locationTextView`. You can also try out `android:weightSum="3"` (or that is appropriate instead of 3) on your root `LinearLayout`. Assign proper weights to your different child views. You can get help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

For showing text in a presentable way, you could use `android:ellipsize="marquee"` or other options available.

Comment: Thank you. It looks much better if I do as you said.

Comment: Do you also know how I can set the textView1 to show only a part of the whole text? Because I have texts of different lengths in my list and it looks ugly.

Comment: You can use `android:ellipsize="marquee"` or other options such as `start`, `end`... it would make your display better