# How to create Jugnoo like location UI . Mapview and below that is viewpager?

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface, android-fragments

I want to create jugnoon like mapview and below that viewpager as shown in image for sample. 
Any hint or idea or sample would be helpful. I am not able to understand where to start. I tried frame layout, relative layout but it all failed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deEbH.png)

Comment: Linear Layout definitely helps you using weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me but I suggest using a linear layout and assigning weight sum to it and provide weight for individual layouts according to the weight sum of the linear layout. A rough example would be assigning a weight sum of 10 to the linear layout and set weight of your map layout to 7 and 3 for the tab layout and whatever comes underneath it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check image attach to question. i want to implement that with within scroll view. For that UI i need guidance.

Comment: Yes, my answer is based on that only. Use a Linear layout as parent layout. Assign a weightsum to that layout. Give weight to the child layouts as required. Your child layouts would be a frame layout and a relative layout containing tab layout. If you are not familiar with the concept of weightsum try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work