# how to set layout_weight of the textview in a fragment in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-layout-weight

I am making a program on ListView + Checkbox in a fragment, but the presentation is creating problem...
Actually i have set layout_weight of the textview and checkbox  but it is not working, so i want to set it programatically, And the checkbox+textview that i am refering are not in the current layout,actually i am inflating it in the current layout. And i didnt find any of the previous example, implementing in a fragment... please have a look at my code and please help me

Here is my code:

fragment_packages.XML:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:id="@+id/packages_list"/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="start|end"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_total"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="9"
android:text="@string/totalcost"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
<TextView
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/price"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_gravity="end"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

packages_items.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    >

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_weight="6"
        />
<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PackagesFragment extends Fragment
{
MyCustomAdpater adpater=null;
ArrayList<PackagesItems> packagesList=null;
ListView listView;
TextView priceView;
private float totalPrice=0f;

private class ViewHolder
{
    TextView textView;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
    View rootView;


    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_packages,container,false);
    listView=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.packages_list);
    priceView=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.price);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           PackagesItems packagesItems = (PackagesItems) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

if(holder.checkBox.isChecked())
{
holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
packagesItems.setSelected(!holder.checkBox.isChecked());
                subtractPrice(packagesList.get(position));
            }
            else {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                packagesItems.setSelected(holder.checkBox.isChecked());
                addPrice(packagesList.get(position));
            }
            }
    });
    displayListView();

    return rootView;
}



public void displayListView()
{

    packagesList = new ArrayList<PackagesItems>();
    PackagesItems packagesItems = new PackagesItems("Hair Cut",150.00f,false);
    packagesList.add(packagesItems);
    packagesItems = new PackagesItems("Hair Spa",300.00f,false);
    packagesList.add(packagesItems);
    packagesItems = new PackagesItems("Facial",300.00f,false);
    packagesList.add(packagesItems);
    packagesItems = new PackagesItems("Make Up",300.00f,false);
    packagesList.add(packagesItems);

    adpater = new MyCustomAdpater(getActivity(),R.layout.packages_items,packagesList);

    listView.setAdapter(adpater);

}

private class MyCustomAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<PackagesItems>
{

    private ArrayList<PackagesItems> packagesList;

    public MyCustomAdpater(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PackagesItems> packagesList)
    {

        super(context,textViewResourceId,packagesList);

        this.packagesList = packagesList;


    }




    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder=null;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.packages_items,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.items);
            holder.checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            holder.checkBox.setTextSize(25);
            holder.checkBox.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            convertView.setTag(holder);


            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb= (CheckBox)v;
                    PackagesItems packagesItems = (PackagesItems)cb.getTag();
                    ;
                    if(cb.isChecked())
                    {
                        addPrice(packagesList.get(position));
                        packagesItems.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subtractPrice(packagesList.get(position));
                        packagesItems.setSelected(!cb.isChecked());
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        PackagesItems packagesItems = packagesList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(String.valueOf(packagesItems.getPrice()));
        holder.checkBox.setText(packagesItems.getItem());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(packagesItems.isSelected());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(packagesItems);
        return convertView;
    }


}

public void addPrice(PackagesItems packagesItems)
{float currentItemPrice;
    currentItemPrice= packagesItems.getPrice();

    totalPrice=totalPrice+currentItemPrice;

    priceView.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
}
public void subtractPrice(PackagesItems packagesItems)
{float currentItemPrice;
    currentItemPrice= packagesItems.getPrice();

    totalPrice=totalPrice-currentItemPrice;

    priceView.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
}

public void setView()
{

    //I WANT TO DO THE STUFF HERE, IN THIS METHOD - setView() !!!
}
```

}

Comment: You need to set the `layout_width` on the `CheckBox` to `0dp`.

Comment: `<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: You can use  <CheckedTextView> is very simple !

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use weight in linearlayout like this.if you take oriantaion vertical then textview hieght is taken "0dp" or if you take oriantaion horizontal then textview width is "odp" taken zero

Comment: i have done it. But its not working.. please have a look at my code and tell me..

Answer (score 0):

change your packages_items.XML: file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    >

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_weight="2"
        />
<TextView
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

here in you can find the difference that in checkbox you define the width wrap content but when be use layout weight then we have to define height/width one of them 0dp

as per our last comment you can do one thing change our xml and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
        >

  <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"

        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and in your adpater get the reference of checkbox and use `checkbox..setText("your text");` i hope it work if it dont so please post the view in the form of image what you exactly looking for

Comment: Thanks but here i am discussing in context of check box  width wrap_content

Comment: sorry but it did not help me.. Please tell me how to do it programtically ?

Comment: Mayur may i know what exact your issue is because view will be created as per the code i think you are having a problem in checkbox check  uncheck so please let us know

Comment: Sir, i am trying to link listview with checkbox through a custom arrayadapter, in which i infilate the the layout containing the checkbox in the listview, but i am not getting proper presentation, like 70% of screen should show checkbox.text named(checkbox), and 30% should show textview named textview... Please help..

Comment: mayur please read my post again i already change it as per your requirement

Comment: please provide me ur personal emailid, i am not able to post my further question here... mine is- Mayursaini1987@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

> How will `android:weight` work without `android:weightSum` ?

Example of how `android:weightSum` works :

You have a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and you have 3 ImageViews inside it and you want these ImageViews always to take equal space.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
```

You can set the `layout_weight` of each `ImageView` to **1** and the `weightSum` in `LinearLayout` to **3** to achieve this.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"/>
```

The good point is that this will work correctly for any device, which will not happen if you set width and height directly.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7452788/3565182)