# What is the difference between layout_weight, weight and weightSum in android and when should each be used?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I know all of them are used to define screen size independent layouts, but how and when should each one be used specifically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3996044/3678308 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12776742/3678308 read these question for understanding....

Comment: Exactly this^ , not a duplicate of 1 question, but of these two combined.