# Android- Part of the button is deleted from the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a linear layout with 3 buttons, with center alignment.

However, after setting some of the weight and putting spaces in between, the last button have like 1/4 of it deleted from the layout, invisible and not clickable. The other parts work perfectly fine though.

Sorry its a new account so I couldn't embed the screenshot, instead please click the following link:

[Here is a picture of the apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLaj0.png)

and please also see the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4">
<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<!--Nesting Structured Layout-->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <!--This is for the Start button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/starting_button"/>
    <!--Spacing-->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <!--This is for the Message button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/liitle_message_button"/>
    <!--Spacing-->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <!--This is for the Settings button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem of the code which cause the problem? And is there any other better approach to achieve the same result?

P.S I am sorry that as a non-native English user, I apologize in advance for it might have loads of grammatical mistakes or asking in an impolite manner, please let me know if you feel offended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using **weights** and **weightSum** for assigning height, the **heights are fixed** in the 'LinearLayout', so your last button goes out of the *fixed height*.

Your problem is fixed by simply removing `android:weightSum="10"` from the inner LinearLayout. You can read more about weightSum [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <!--Nesting Structured Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <!--This is for the Start button-->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="b1"/>
        <!--Spacing-->
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <!--This is for the Message button-->
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="b2"/>
        <!--Spacing-->
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <!--This is for the Settings button-->
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="b3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of using `space` you can center your layout using `android:gravity` or `android:layout:gravity`.

Also using nested weights are not good for performance.

Comment: I am sorry for my late reply

Comment: since I am new to stackoverflow, I thought I would have email everytime I got an answer... but seems its not the how the way it works TAT

Comment: but is nested weights really that bad for performance? or is it just a minor problem

Comment: I think you won't see much on newer devices, older devices may start skipping frames, also if these answers helped you may select one and mark this question as solved.

Comment: ohhhh I have not realized it

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the weightSum your weight sum at LinearLayout is 10 but when you add the weight value of the buttons and space in the LinearLayout the result is 11 so the weightSum in the second LinearLayout must to be 11.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work) you have a question that gives more clarification to weightSum.
simply your code must be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4">
<Space
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
<!--Nesting Structured Layout-->
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:weightSum="11"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="2">

<!--This is for the Start button-->
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="@string/starting_button"/>
<!--Spacing-->
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<!--This is for the Message button-->
<Button
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="@string/liitle_message_button"/>
<!--Spacing-->
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<!--This is for the Settings button-->
<Button
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="@string/settings_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
<Space
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make it very complicated , you can achieve it very easily by using Relative layout and Linear Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="START" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="LITTLE MESSAGE" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SETTINGS" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I guess it will be a much better approac

Comment: @Noobnewbier  Thanks , please upvote if you like the answer mate

Comment: I think i did thumbs up, but the fact that I am having a very low reputation makes it not showing on the chart

Comment: @Noobnewbier, No problem mate, I am glad your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="START" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="MIDDLE" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="LAST" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
    Attaching image also
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for my late reply tho, my problem is solved due to you guys' efforts

Answer (score 0):

Use this simplified code to achieve same result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp">

    <!--This is for the Start button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/starting_button" />

    <!--This is for the Message button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/liitle_message_button" />

    <!--This is for the Settings button-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: thanks!
I added the space to ensure everyone of them will have a same width tho