# Android Layout Weight distribution

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am doing the [following course at udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud834/lessons/4330701752/concepts/42042586730923). It's about Android User Interface.

As a part of my course I used an XML visualizer.

http://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/#/android/linear-layout-weight

Now upon experimenting I entered the following code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ocean"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight = "1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="You're invited!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:background="#009688" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"

        android:background="#009688" />

</LinearLayout>
```

as per my understanding, by using android:layout_weight the whole parent layout is divided as per priority and distributed accordingly, if so,  the space after distributing among image and "You're invited!" there should only be remaining space enough, to fill out "Bonfire at the beach".

Then why there is a empty space below "Bonfire at the beach" ?

(Also if possible can anyone please explain how the control flows among XML code).

UPDATE
when I added  android:layout_weight = "0" in "Bonfire at the beach" then there is no empty space below. Can any one explain why this happens and why there is space in previous case. and this is the code is used.

before
[image]

after

[image]

even tried setting height to 0dp

[image]

Comment: You are not using weight in the Bonfire at the beach TextView. If you use it, it will work. put height=0dp and weight=1

Comment: add `android:layout_weight = "1"` property into second textview

Comment: yes but by default layout weight is value is 0 . and Yes i do understand that 0dp in height and weight to 1 works. What is want to know exactly is how the space is being distributed among the parent layout. and why reason why there is space below "Bonfire at the beach"

Comment: @Srinadh kch  did you get that now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @Srinadh kch check my answer! EDit 2 Read everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understand it using the below example**

Weight defines how much space a view will consume compared to other views within a `LinearLayout`.

Weight is used when you want to give specific screen space to one component compared to other.

**Key Properties**:

- [`weightSum`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) is the overall sum of weights of all child views. If you don't specify the `weightSum`, the system will calculate the sum of all the weights on its own.
- [`layout_weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) specifies the amount of space out of the total weight sum
  the widget will occupy.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type Your Text Here" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The output is:

[image]

Now even if the size of the device is larger, the EditText will take 2/4 of the screen's space. Hence the look of your app is seen consistent across all screens.

[This if before you edit your question might be irrelevant now

Now in your ***Bonfire at the beach*** there is no weight and its `wrap_content` so there is no grantee that it will take the remaining space! and that space can remain after adding it will differ with the screen size of device ]

**Note:**
Here the `layout_width` is kept `0dp` as the widget space is divided horizontally. If the widgets are to be aligned vertically `layout_height` will be set to `0dp`.

This is done to increase the efficiency of the code because at runtime the system won't attempt to calculate the width or height respectively as this is managed by the weight. If you instead used `wrap_content` the system would attempt to calculate the width/height first before applying the weight attribute which causes another calculation cycle.

---

**Lets Move to your XML** 
see how i used them

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"   //<-------------------
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/mc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight = "1"/> //<-------------------

    <TextView
        android:text="You're invited!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:layout_weight = "1" //<-------------------
        android:background="#009688" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight = "1" //<------------------- if you remove this , this text view will be gone cuz its 0 by default
        android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:background="#009688" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you ask what if you have not given `android:layout_weight` ,Default weight is **zero**. Zero means view will not be shown, that empty space will remain there

Since you don't believe you can read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) 
[image]

---

**EDIT: 2**

Since you said that, i went through [android-visualizer](http://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/#/android/linear-layout-weight) that you use
and Have you ever noticed this...

> "Line 6: The attribute `android:weight_sum` is not supported here."

thing on its bottom.

Meaning they are not providing that functionality to adjust your layout boundaries. Its just a simple online tool.I am
not saying it is not recommended to use, but my personal idea is, you
can't touch the depth of android if you use that.

Now if you want a confirmation  what actually happens have a look on android studio/ eclipse  as well  which are read IDE s

This is android studio

[image]

Can you see any view contain your text "Bonfire at the beach"? no 
Instead a.studio display a red line in XML.

> Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible

Because there is no `layout_weight` is given and we have added 0 height

Now you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Ok I got height to 0dp part but can u elaborate a bit regarding why there is space below "Bonfire at the beach". Thank you :)

Comment: nd if you are wondering how the image is up there its in the available images down left.

Comment: @Srinadh make your `LinearLayout` `android:weightSum=3` and use `android:layout_weight="1"` on two views and see

Comment: hmm . :( i added the line android:weightSum ="4" in root and even tried 3 t still remains the same. :( there is space below Bonfire at the beach. and also i set android:layout_height="0dp" for Bonfire at the beach but still the space appears.

Comment: if i made android:layout_weight="1" in  "Bonfire at the beach" then  all the there children would divide the space equally. I am not getting the why empty space below part when weight = "0" (the default value).

Comment: wait !! when i specified android:layout_weight="0" then there is no space appearing below. Hmm do you know the reason why it happens like so :(

Comment: @Srinadh kch you got it right its default weight = "0" and 0 means don't allocate space

Comment: No i think there is something different in default value. As if I explicitly specify android:layout_weight = "0" then there is no space. but if not specified there appears a space below.

Comment: @Srinadh kch ill show you the doc. Have you specified the root view for a weight_Sum ? take the edited xml of yours that i added and compare

Comment: Updated the pics. :)

Comment: @Srinadh kch yes exactly you gave the layout_weight for what `android:orientation=` its `vertical` so verticaly its now divided

Comment: @Srinadh but still you are not getting the way..why dont you read what i said in my answer here >"Note: Here the layout_width is kept 0dp as the widget space is divided horizontally. If the widgets are to be aligned vertically layout_height will be set to 0dp." yet you have sizes like 400,100

Comment: yes i even tried that 0dp for heights but still the problem is same

Comment: @Srinadh kch  can you re change the images of your currant status , may be i can explain then