# Android Studio: Content goes off screen

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Part of my UI goes off-screen when installed on an actual android device. It uses the Google maps API. The "my location" button goes a little bit off screen.

Also the map doesn't cover the complete screen even though it does in the UI preview in Android Studio.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="269dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/SearchLocationText"
    android:hint="Search Location"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"
    />

<Button
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:onClick="onSearch" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context="com.anand.projectv10.MapsActivity1"
    android:layout_height="519dp"
    android:layout_width="382dp" />
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot? and now what do you want to achieve ? Also note that you have given hard code vales all over your view so that can happen!! eg: width="269dp ,height="519dp

Comment: I have added a screenshot now.

Comment: I've given the answer already!

Answer (score 1):

You have a preview of what you are designing at android studio.So you will design something to cover that screen but note that every screen is not with the same dimensions(width/height/dpi). When you hardcore values there is a high possibility to make view positions go wrong in real scenarios.Values assigned based on ratios always stick fine.

You can use `weightSum` and `layout_weight` to achieve what you want without hard coding values

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/SearchLocationText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Search Location"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onSearch"
                android:text="Search" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.anand.projectv10.MapsActivity1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

For further understanding Read 
[What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

[What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)