# Android dynamically added button's width not fit to its text

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Dynamically added buttons to a linearlayout in my toolbar do render a weird way :
It looks like the width of the button created in my code and passed to my view has a random width. I have set layoutparams to "wrap content" but it isn't making any difference. Any clue on how to fix it ? I'd like my buttons to fit to the text they contain, not bigger nor smaller.

Toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="@color/Blue"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/app_name_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingTop="3dp"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textSize="14dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:text="@string/app_name" />

      <!-- dynamically button will be here-->
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`
```

My code to add the buttons :

```
var layout_toolbar = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout_toolbar);

//Add arrow image
ImageView arrow = new ImageView(context);
arrow.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.arrow);
arrow.Id = ariane_lvl_count;

layout_toolbar.AddView(arrow);

//set layoutparams for arrow image
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_arrow = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
lp_arrow.Gravity = GravityFlags.Left|GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
lp_arrow.LayoutParameters = lp_arrow;

//Add button
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.Id = ariane_lvl_count;
btn.TextSize = 15;
var folder = (currentFolder + gridViewString[e.Position] + "/");
btn.Hint = folder;
btn.Text = gridViewString[e.Position];
btn.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
btn.SetSingleLine(true);
btn.SetTextColor(Resources.GetColor(Color.Yellow));

layout_toolbar.AddView(btn);

//set  layoutparams for button
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_btn = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent);
lp_btn.Gravity = GravityFlags.Left|GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
btn.LayoutParameters = lp_btn;
```

How it renders : 
[image: elements underlined in red take too much space and do not fit to text like others do]

elements underlined in red take too much space and do not fit to text like others do

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea for you. Why not try to create sample layouts (example : a button layout) and load it into your Toolbar with layoutInflater. Or make a weightSum in the toolbar.

[Understanding Android LayoutInflater](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)
[Understanding Android weightSum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thanks for helping but the weightsum is not what I need, I already have used it somewhere else. I gave it a try with the inflater but it behaves the same way.