# Can we use android:layout_weight without adding android:weightSum to parent ? If yes, what are the problems may come?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Whether `android:weightSum` is mandatory or not to use `android:layout_weight` ?
Can we use directly `android:layout_weight` inside a `linearlayout` without assign `android:weightSum`. Anyone please tell me pros and cons of using `android:layout_weight`and without `android:weightSum`.  Thanks in advance.

Sample code:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/table_view"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                style="@style/BaseButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                style="@style/BaseButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/pause"
                android:textColor="@color/teal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                style="@style/BaseButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/stop" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use android:layout_weight without adding android:weightSum to
>   parent ?

**Yes,** We can. Consider the example below -

[image: Consider this example],

If, you want to design the row like `Terms & Condition` which is having `TextView` and `ImageButton` to the right. It will goes like:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Width of TextView = Width of LinearLayout - width of ImageButton -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_back_black_18dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

For concept of `WeightSum`, You may refer this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: My doubt is LinearLayout doesn't set attribute weighSum. but children are having android:layout_weight with same or different weights.
In your example only one child has android:layout_weight. for all child has weight where LinearLayout doesn't have weighSum.

Comment: When you are using multiple weights, you must have to define `weightSum` to let the system measure - view height or width according to its parent (your case). While when you want to have one children to occupy whole the parent dimes, just use weight on that specific child, rest of child will occupy their dimen automatically(which is my case) .

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use the weight without defining the weight sum in parent. IN that case the total weight of the child is calculated by adding the weight of each child.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"/>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"/>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The parent layout will now automatically take the weight sum as 3(sum of weight of each child)

Here are the more resources on this topic

[What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

and  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html