# Android layout_weight is not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to set `android:layout_weight="1"` but it does not do anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fbd0d5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.raza.helloworld.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Minnions"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Happy"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Birthday"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: In your Linear Layout(root view) replace android:weightSum="3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove android:weightSum="1" from root layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fbd0d5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Minnions"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Happy"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Birthday"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: aw sum thanks for your help i am learning android development it helps

Answer (score 0):

Changes the weightsum to 3 in parent linear Layout

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `weigtsum` and `showIn`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fbd0d5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Minnions"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Happy"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fef65b"
        android:text="Birthday"
        android:textColor="#f44242"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the weightsum of your LinearLayout to equal 3.

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

[This other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work) povides a bit more detail about weight sum but the gist of it is:

The child elements `layout_weight` should equal to the parent's `weight_sum`.

Comment: It works when i remove   
android:weightSum="1" from root layout

Answer (score 0):

All your views have the **same weight**!. So none of their height will be changed.change weightSum to be equal to the sum of weight of its children and set different weights for child views. It'll Change then.

Like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fbd0d5"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="#fef65b"
    android:text="Minnions"
    android:textColor="#f44242"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#fef65b"
    android:text="Happy"
    android:textColor="#f44242"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#fef65b"
    android:text="Birthday"
    android:textColor="#f44242"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fef65b"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hai"
    android:textColor="#f44242"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fef65b"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#f44242"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fef65b"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="How r u"
    android:textColor="#f44242"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```