# Android Layouts and Auto Scaling Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Android App that I am setting up to handle screen rotation and with the landscape position fragment, I am putting together a Linear Layout with that contains 2 fragments that I will to sit side by side and fill the screen.  The only thing that escapes me is how to auto fill the screen with the two fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout weight attribute to do this. Check this answer for further explanation [What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)