# RecyclerView in dialog takes up (almost) whole area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a dialog with layout

**subject_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subject_name"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
            android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/please_wait"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/studentRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/switcher"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/ok_Btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="ok"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the dialog is created, I am fetching data from server to populate RecyclerView. At that time ViewPager's first child (with the progressbar) is visible. When I get data from server I set RecyclerView as visible child.

The problem here is, **when RecyclerView have a lot of rows, the button under under ViewSwitcher containing the RecyclerView is only partially visible** (Like, one third of the button is not visible).

**Screenshot** (How it is not supposed to look)

[image]

But when the recyclerView doesn't have that much rows its showing as expected,

**Screenshot** (How it is supposed to look)

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: If your list of names is regularly long then a `BottomSheet` could be a better fit than a `Dialog`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html

Comment: remove `30dp` height and weight from the and make as `wrap_content`.

Comment: @sushildlh weight of button?

Comment: yeah ...........

Comment: @Kuffs I have already used the bottom sheet once in that same activity (Take a look at the second screenshot). I think it is not desirable to create another bottomsheet from that bottomsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are adding weight for linear layout point to keep in mind are:

Give android:weightSum="1" as one and child layout weight from 0.0 to 1.0
ex:android:layout_weight="0.3"

Use layout weight as 0dp instead pf hardcoded value ex:  android:layout_height="0dp" instead of android:layout_height="30dp"

Try this layout instead.Hope it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subject_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/please_wait" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/studentRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok_Btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/switcher"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can keep the button size 30dp fixed?

Comment: I did this like you posted, but button was kinda big, so i fixed button size as 30dp and it works. But isn't it a dirty fix? Am I overriding the weight aspect by setting fixed size?

Comment: I concept of weight is to give specific height or width for view to occupy in every different screens.May be you should try to reduce button weight and check.

Comment: Try like this..remove weightsum from Linearlayout,add layout_weight to ViewSwitcher as 1,then add height of button to 30dp.If you find my answer satisfactory please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain your **weightSum** and **weight** properly in layout.for more knowledge you may check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work) and apply like this

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
            android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/please_wait"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/studentRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_below="@id/switcher"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/ok_Btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="ok"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you just removed the weight?

Comment: No, I didn't remove the weight but I changed the value of weight in LinearLayout and Button ,also set the height "0dp" in both.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: ofcourse , You can also modify the value of weight as per your requirement.

Comment: Thats kinda OK'ish on first case (with a lot of rows). But for the second case ( second screenshot ) Button is way too big.

Comment: That's why I suggested you to change the value of weight as per your need in LinearLayout and Button.

Comment: @AswinPAshok have look on answer . It will defiantly work.

Comment: @AswinPAshok , If  have face any problem to make change the value of weight then let me know.

Comment: Changing the weight is not reliable I think (It changes buttonheight proportionally to recyclerview height, when RecyclerView is too long and I somehow managed to make it work, button will look weird in the other case and vice versa )

Answer (score 0):

use **android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"** in recycle view

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: No change. Still the same

Comment: also add same in ok button

Comment: adding layout_marginBottom="30dp" did the trick but it messed up the other case (RecyclerView with fewer rows), now that looks weird.

Comment: only use ok button height android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subject_name"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/please_wait"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/switcher"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/ok_Btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried something like this before.Now the button is not visible. So I added Linear layout with weight to make it somewhat visible

Answer (score 0):

Ok Check now!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subject_name"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/subject_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please wait"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/studentRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/ok_Btn"
        android:layout_below="@id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#369"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would look weird for that second screenshot (with just two rows).

Comment: Eventhough the height of that RelativeLayout (the one you replaced the linearLayout with) is `wrap_content`, for the second case it fills the entire screen.

Comment: Did you try to execute my code?  I have changed a few things in it

Comment: [ScreenShot 1](https://ibb.co/dvSj8k) , [ScreenShot 2](https://ibb.co/jCbBok) after edits

Comment: Now button is not visible in First case [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/c6Pgok)