# Android Layout supporting all Device

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I fix my layout for all devices using a single layout file?
This question has been answered many times, but those answers are not helping me out. My app is looking perfect on a 5 inch screen but on others the alignment is different.

Comment: Can you post your layout file? Maybe we can help you from there

Comment: Please post the xml and some pictures of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to make an app fits across all kind of devices is to use **WeightSum** while designing your app layout,

http://www.northborder-software.com/getting_started_part16.html

[What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)