# Can someone explain how this weightsum work? and why

Tags: android, android-layout

When i check the design for this code. this WeightSum act totally opposite the way i want. when i set my button weightSum for 70 it takes 30 (total weightSum is 100) vise-versa.

```
  <LinearLayout
         android:weightSum="100"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

             <Button
                 android:layout_weight="70"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button" />

             <ToggleButton
                 android:layout_weight="30"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="ToggleButton" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `android:weightSum` defines the maximum weight sum of `Layout`, and it is calculate total sum of the `layout_weight` of all the its children views.

**Example:-** a LinearLayout having 3 Views(Which can be anything). Now you want to show 3 views equally in screen. So need to put `layout_weight` to views 1 and your `weightSum` is 3.

```
<LinearLayout
         android:weightSum="100"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

             <View
                 android:layout_weight="70"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button" />

             <View
                 android:layout_weight="30"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp`enter code here`"
                 android:text="ToggleButton" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

or You can also put your `android:layout_weight` in `points` also like below :-

```
<LinearLayout
         android:weightSum="1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

             <View
                 android:layout_weight=".7"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button" />

             <View
                 android:layout_weight=".3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp`enter code here`"
                 android:text="ToggleButton" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

**Remember 3 thing before use `android:weightSum` :-**

> 1. set the android:layout_width of the children to "0dp"
> 2. set the android:weightSum of the parent (edit: as Jason Moore noticed, this attribute is optional, because by default it is set to
>      the children's layout_weight sum)
> 3. set the android:layout_weight of each child proportionally (e.g. weightSum="5", three children: layout_weight="1", layout_weight="3",
>      layout_weight="1")

Answer (score 3):

You need set `android:layout_width="0dp"` of **Button** and **ToggleButton**.

Comment: or 0px. 0 is still 0... :)

Answer (score 1):

you have set children view's width=0 if LinearLayout orientation is horizontal and height = 0 if orientation is vertical
I have made changes to your code, please refer :)

```
 <LinearLayout
         android:weightSum="100"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

             <Button
                 android:layout_weight="70"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button" />

             <ToggleButton
                 android:layout_weight="30"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="ToggleButton" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

It works on percentage basis, When you want to make your views' height and width to occupy certain percentage of its parent then weights is the solution
e.g. if `weightSum = 1` children can be of `weight_layout` .30 and.60. So basically addition of children's' `layout_weight` should be equals to `weightSum` of their parent (or less in WRT use cases)

Answer (score 0):

based orientation, you should set `layout_height` or `layout_width` of parent layout to **0dp** for correct behavior of weightsum.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work well, as others have pointed, the width (or height, if the `LinearLayout` orientation was vertical) should be 0 (px or dp, whatever you wish, as it's still 0) for the children that have a weight.

About explanation of how it works, if not all had weight, the remaining one would be spread to them.

In your case, you don't have to set `weightSum` at all, because you've already set the weight for each of them (70+30 is indeed 100).

What it will do (after the needed changes), is set the first View to have a width that's 30% of the width of the parent, and the second view with 70% of the width of the parent.