# How to listview"s under set button with edittext in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design one layout in LinearLayout. My purpose is; Setting one ListView full layout_width. ListView goes to end of others height. After that; There are an EditText and a button. EditText is layout_width 4/3 button . 4/1. How can I do these?

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/mesajlaşma_listview"
       >


    </ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"

    >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:hint="Mesaj Yaz."
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:text="Gönder."
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </Button>
        />


</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use LinearLayout weightsum, and then set individualy views weight. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work .

Comment: I know these. But How can I do ListView.When It height is match_parent.It erase buton and editText.

Comment: Then what about creating the Button and EditText in the LinearLayout first, and after that create the ListView to fill the remaining space?

Comment: You are genius.It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the Button and EditText in a LinearLayout first, then create a ListView and let it fill the remaining space of the screen.