# Moving an image to the center in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder how to move the `linearLayout2` to the center of `linearLayout1?`
The imageView should be in the center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:id="@+id/appsLogo"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="220dp"
                  android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/appsLogo"
                  android:background="@color/white"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:textSize="25dp"
                  android:text="Choose an option"/>

        <Button android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
                android:background="@color/lightseagreen"
                android:text="Camera"/>

        <Button android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey"
                android:text="Gallery"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Current Output**

[image]

`linearLayout2` should move up until reach the `imageView` center.

Comment: What is your expected output and current output can u share screenshot for both

Comment: Use constraint layout or RelativeLayout or framelayout for your requirements.

Comment: @NileshRathod post updated.

Comment: @JohnJoe and what is What is your expected output

Comment: @NileshRathod `linearLayout2` should move up until reach the `imageView` center.

Comment: Of course it won't work since it is a `LinearLayout` ! Use a `RelativeLayout` on the root

Comment: use android layout weight and weighSum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work this will give u an idea about it

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` or `ConstrainLayout` as a parent layout.

Comment: @JohnJoe check my answer below it will give you what you want

Comment: how about setting your image as background to your linear layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using **`RelativeLayout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appsLogo"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_marker"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/appsLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Choose an option"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Camera" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Choose an option"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Camera" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_marker"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: not familiar with `CoordinatorLayout`, but the answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to your Linear Layout 2. Difference between `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` is explained:

**`android:layout_gravity="center"`**
This will set the layout to the center of its parent layout.

**`android:gravity="center"`** This will set the child contents of this layout at its center.

For more detailed explanations on the difference between these two, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android).